# How to draw random numbers from a gamma distribution without the Statistics Toolbox?

Tags: matlab, random, distribution, gamma-distribution

I am varying the signal strength for synthetic images. I need the signal to vary between 0 and 0.1, but I need to do this with a gamma distribution so that more of them fall around the .01/.02 range. The problem is that I am using the 2010 version of Matlab without the Statistics Toolbox that doesn't have the `gamrnd` function a part of its library.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [Inverse transform sampling method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling) to convert a uniform distribution to any other distribution:

```
P = rand(1000);
X = gaminv(P(:),2,2); % with k = 2 and theta = 2
```

Here is a litle demonstration:

```
for k = [1 3 9]
    for theta = [0.5 1 2]
        X = gaminv(P(:),k,theta);
        histogram(X,50)
        hold on
    end
end
```

Which gives:

[image: gamma dist]

---

**Edit:**

Without the statistics toolbox, you can use the [*Marsaglia's simple transformation-rejection method*](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nb5laosvu6xgjhn/A%20Simple%20Method%20for%20Generating%20Gamma%20Variables.pdf?dl=0) to generate random numbers from gamma distribution with `rand` and `randn`:

```
N = 10000; % no. of tries
% distribution parameters:
a = 0.5;
b = 0.1;
% Marsaglia's simple transformation-rejection:
d = a - 1/3;
x = randn(N,1);
U = rand(N,1);
v = (1+x./sqrt(9*d)).^3;
accept = log(U)<(0.5*x.^2+d-d*v+d*log(v));
Y = d*(v(accept)).*b;
```

Now `Y` is distributed like gamma(a,b). We can test the result using the `gamrnd` function:

```
n = size(Y,1);
X = gamrnd(a,b,n,1);
```

And the histograms of `Y`, and `X` are:

[image: gamma dist 2]

However, keep in mind that gamma distribution might not fit your needs because it has [no specific upper bound](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/134863/122914) (i.e. goes to infinity). So you may want to use another (bounded) distribution, like beta divided by 10.

Comment: This version of matlab does not know what gaminv means.

Comment: @Kelsey do you have the **Statistics Toolbox**?

Comment: Yeah it is weird that it doesn't recognize it. I don't have the toolbox. I have found the distribution on wikipedia, but I am not sure how to use it to create random numbers between 0 - 0.1.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution#Generating_gamma-distributed_random_variables

Comment: `gaminv` is part of the toolbox, so you won't be able to use it.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try that. We also just went over the gamma distribution in my stats class. I realize this isn't the best way to do this, but I am doing it for work. And the boss really wants the gamma distribution. But I will talk to him about other possibilities. Again, thank you.

Comment: This actually ended up not being what I needed. My statistics professor was able to help. Excel has a gamma function and I used the gamma inverse function to create the data points I needed and imported that data into Matlab. But thank you for the quick replies and all of the help.